# Check file extension with regex - application/vnd.ms-excel

Tags: javascript, regex, excel, upload

I need to check if a file is a xls. I am trying this code, but I upload a xls file and I am getting the error Invalid file.

```
var acceptFileTypes = /(.|\/)(application\/vnd.ms-excel)$/i;

console.log(data.originalFiles[0]['type']); //application/vnd.ms-excel 

if (!acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['type'])) {
        uploadErrors.push('Invalid file');
}
```

There is something wrong with the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your error: `(.|\/)`

This part needs to consume one character - it is actually equivalent to `.`.

Remove that part and you'll be fine. You also need to escape the periods:

```
var acceptFileTypes = /application\/vnd\.ms-excel$/i;
```

Of course, this is equivalent to:

```
var acceptFileTypes = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
var isExcel = yourFile.toLowerCase().indexOf(acceptFileTypes, yourFile.length - acceptFileTypes.length) == 0;
```